# Use name with whitespace for qmake TARGET variable

Tags: ios, bash, qt, qt-creator, qmake

iOS/OS X application names usually contains spaces (like "App Store.app").
But when i'm trying to use such name in my Qt/ios project like this:

```
ios: TARGET = "My Cool App"
```

build process failed with strange error in the autogenerated by Qt Bash script.

Am i doing something wrong, or such whitespaces in names just don't supported?

**UPD**
the problem first time occurs in qmake-generated shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cp -r $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$FULL_PRODUCT_NAME /Users/eraxillan/Projects/<PROJECT_DIR>
```

If `$FULL_PRODUCT_NAME` contains spaces, then script just fails.
Script generated and executed only in case of custom `DESTDIR` project variable value - my case.
So, looks like a bug in `qmake`-generated script to copy project build artefacts to custom output directory.
**Workarounds:**

- Remove spaces from target name (My Cool App --> my-cool-app)
- Do not use custom `DESTDIR` value at all

Hope this will be helpful

Comment: make itself doesn't deal with spaces in targets/names at all well (or really at all). That's just a fact of how the language works.

Comment: But how the XCode manage to build applications like "App Store.app"?
It thinks it uses make internally, like Qt Creator/qmake do

Comment: I don't believe it does (though it certainly could) and what the resulting file name is at the end (assuming that's the only thing you are worried about) isn't related to how the build itself works. You can always rename it (and put the spacey-name in plist/etc. files).

Comment: I'm not sure what just renaming compiled bundle will be enough :(
Looks like qmake's `TARGET` do smth more

Comment: The question isn't what `TARGET` does as much as it is can you use a different `TARGET` and then just rename the bundle to get the application name you want. And you may not be able to, it may be more complicated than that. I don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

> TARGET = My" "Cool" "App

Comment: (Sorry for necro-answer) But unfortunately it don't :(

Comment: are you sure you used single char ", not double '?

Comment: Yes, i am. Still got the same error:
`/bin/sh -c \"<PROJECT_DIR>/Script-9C316F444A62BF296E3E1F25.sh\"
cp: /Users/eraxillan/Projects/<PROJECT_NAME>/Debug-iphonesimulator/My: No such file or directory`

Comment: I have tested it on Qt 5.9 and it worked, maybe it fixed or changed on Qt 5.10 or other versions

Comment: Maybe, because i'm using Qt 5.10.1. So, looks like a bug/regression

Comment: Just tried, it works for me on macOS 10.13, got filename with space. Qt 5.10.1

Comment: Ok, can you share your test project somehow (github etc.)? and i will mark your answer as solution

Comment: I have created empty project and add TARGET = My" "Cool" "App to .pro file, got file name with two spaces

Comment: Yep, finally i got it! empty project really works, but mine don't - probably because i disable shadow build. This is my further problem